# Argument exception when trying to save to SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

Unable to perform validation on `DataRow` column. The column in the back
end is allowing `null`, but is still throwing exceptions. When I tried to save with a `null` value in `cellNumber.Text` it shouldn't throw exception I tried to validate with if statement but didn't work either. Please help.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["FirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
    dr["LastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
    dr["Shirt"] = txtShirt.Text;
    dr["Pant"] = txtPant.Text;
    if (dr.IsNull("CellNumber"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter Cell number");
    }
    else
    {
        dr["CellNumber"] = txtCellNo.Text; //Argument exception is thrown here
    }
    dr["DueDate"] = txtDueDate.Text;
    dr["Date"] = txtDate.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    try
    {
        da.Update(ds, "Measurement");
    }
    catch (DBConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        dt.Clear();
        da.Fill(ds, "Measurement");
    }
    finally 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** -- SQL is just the **Structured Query Language** - a language used by many database systems, but not a database product... We really need to know what database system (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Dollars to donuts he's using sql server.  He's tagged this as c# and .net programmers often use the term sql database instead of ms sql or sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You might be checking the wrong thing.  You have this:

```
if (dr.IsNull("CellNumber"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter Cell number");
}
else
{
    dr["CellNumber"] = txtCellNo.Text; 
}
dr["CellNumber"] = txtCellNo.Text;//Argument exception is thrown here
```

It would make more sense to check the contents of txtCellNo.Text instead of dr["CellNumber"].